# Localhost/server IP redirect?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, redirection, httpd

I have Apache HTTPD installed on my webserver. There are two websites with two different domains. Let's say `example1.com` and `example2.com`. There are couple of redirects like:

- `http://` -> `https://`
- `http://www` -> `https://`
- `https://www` -> `https://`

for each domain. Everything works fine.

But when you go to http://84.xx.xx.xx (server IP address) there is default Apache page - `It works!`
My question is - is it OK/safe to leave it as it is? Or there should be redirect to `example1.com` for instance? Or should I return 403?

Any thoughts about it?

Comment: That depends on what you want and what that server does. Should people easily know that `example1.com` is hosted on it if they happen to land there using an IP? This is really just up for you to decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about VHOST ?

Open `Drive:\Folder\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

Then add VHOST

```
<VirtualHost example1.com:80>
    ServerName example1.com
    ServerAlias www.example1.com
    DocumentRoot /htdocs/example1.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example1.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost example1.com:80
<VirtualHost 84.xx.xx.xx:80>
    ServerName 84.xx.xx.xx
    Redirect 403 /
    ErrorDocument 403 "Sorry, direct IP access not allowed."
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
    ServerAdmin admin@example1.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    UserDir disabled
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost example2.com:80>
    ServerName example2.com
    ServerAlias www.example2.com
    DocumentRoot /htdocs/example2.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example1.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost example2.com:80
<VirtualHost 84.xx.xx.xx:80>
    ServerName 84.xx.xx.xx
    Redirect 403 /
    ErrorDocument 403 "Sorry, direct IP access not allowed."
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
    ServerAdmin admin@example2.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    UserDir disabled
</VirtualHost>
```